Expected number of consecutive sequences
Let's say we have a string of length n and each character has probability p of being 1 and probability 1-p of being 0. What is the expected value of the number of "islands" of 1s in the string (the number of consecutive sequences of 1s bounded by 0s or the ends of the strings on both sides).
For example, 0011001111101101 would have 4 islands.

I'm going to guess that you should use recursion, but I am not sure yet.

I did guess there's a recursive/dynamic programming solution, eg. dp(x, y) where x is the size of the string and y is a boolean that's true if the last character is a 0 or not. I was wondering if there is a purely analytic solution/solution using linearity of expectation

Let's say the elements of the string are $a_i$ for $1 \le i \le n$. Define
$$X_i = 
\begin{cases}
  1 \qquad \text{if element $a_i$ starts an island of 1s;} \\
  0 \qquad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Then $X_1=1$ if $a_1 = 1$, which happens with probability $p$, and $X_i=1$ for $2 \le i \le n$ if $a_{i-1}=0$ and $a_i = 1$, which happens with probability $(1-p)p$.
The total number of islands is $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, and by linearity of expectation
$$\begin{align}
E \left( \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right) &=  \sum_{i=1}^n E(X_i) \\
&= p + (n-1)(1-p)p 
\end{align}$$

Great solution, this solves the issue I had in the comments of the other answer and is much more concise
